# Set rails request timeout (execution expired)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timeout

Should be an easy one but google isn't helping: can't find a way to get rails to wait longer before a request expires

> ActionView::Template::Error (execution expired)

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

Comment: isn't it server problem? mongrel/webrick/nginx etc

Comment: indeed, we need to know what webserver you're running

Answer (score 6):

First, `gem list` to see your rack_timeout version.

If you're using **rack_timeout <= 0.4** then use

```
Rack::Timeout.timeout = 30 # seconds inside the config/initializers/timeout.rb
```

If you're using **rack_timeout >= 0.5** then use the following environment variables.

```
service_timeout:   15     # RACK_TIMEOUT_SERVICE_TIMEOUT
wait_timeout:      30     # RACK_TIMEOUT_WAIT_TIMEOUT
wait_overtime:     60     # RACK_TIMEOUT_WAIT_OVERTIME
service_past_wait: false  # RACK_TIMEOUT_SERVICE_PAST_WAIT
```

In rails, you can load environment variables in a .env file:

```
gem 'dotenv-rails'
```

In your config/environments/development.rb (or other) do:

```
Dotenv::Railtie.load
```

Then, in the root of your rails project, your .env will look like:

```
RACK_TIMEOUT_SERVICE_TIMEOUT=15
RACK_TIMEOUT_WAIT_TIMEOUT=30
RACK_TIMEOUT_WAIT_OVERTIME=60
RACK_TIMEOUT_SERVICE_PAST_WAIT=false
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, Rack::Timeout.timeout doesn't work anymore since rack-timeout 0.5 ...

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `gem "rack-timeout"`
Then change the `Rack::Timeout.timeout = 30  # seconds` or more inside the `config/initializers/timeout.rb` file.
Use this [link](https://github.com/kch/rack-timeout) for more details.

Comment: Rack::Timeout.timeout has been removed since rack-timeout 0.5 and doesn't work anymore ... see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53302364 for a solution that works.